# MySql: How to get the next record from given condition

Tags: mysql

If there're two tables, one is players, the other is onfield.

table:: player:

```
uid:10, name:jack
uid:23, name:david
uid:37, name:james
uid:42, name:nick
uid:58, name:mark
```

table:: games

```
gid: 20, last_player: david
gid: 32, last_player: jack
gid: 38, last_player: mark
gid: 43, last_player: nick
```

How do I find the next player form a given gid?
I'm looking for some statement like:

```
SELECT p.uid, p.name FROM player p AND onfield o WHERE o.last_player = p.name AND gid=20 ORDER BY uid ASC;
```

If gid=20, the answer is uid: 37, name: james

If gid=38, the answer is uid: 10, name: jack

Question is, I have to get the next record from the statement, and in the case of "last_player='mark'", I have the get the first record.

Is there a way to solve this inside a SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

if  o.last_player  != mark

```
   SELECT p.uid, p.name FROM player p, onfield o WHERE o.last_player = p.name 
   AND p.uid > o.guid ORDER BY uid ASC limit 1;
```

if  o.last_player  == mark

```
  SELECT p.uid, p.name FROM player p, onfield o ORDER BY p.uid ASC limit 1;
```